# How to transpose and split in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

`How do write script for below`

`google form response as below`

| **time stamp** | **Document No.** | **Recipient Name** | **Document transmittal ref no** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/9/2021 21:36:11 | 170709, 170738, 171769, 172003, 172025 | Susan | 20210001 |
| 7/18/2021 18:19:59 | 131034, 131192, 132438, 132465, 133016 | Jhon | 20210002 |

`i want processed data look like below`

| Time stamp | Document no. | Recipient Name | Document transmittal Ref no. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/9/2021 21:36:11 | 170709 | Susan | 20210001 |
| 7/9/2021 21:36:11 | 170738 | Susan | 20210001 |
| 7/9/2021 21:36:11 | 171769 | Susan | 20210001 |
| 7/9/2021 21:36:11 | 172003 | Susan | 20210001 |
| 7/9/2021 21:36:11 | 172025 | Susan | 20210001 |
| 7/18/2021 18:19:59 | 131034 | Jhon | 20210002 |
| 7/18/2021 18:19:59 | 131192 | Jhon | 20210002 |
| 7/18/2021 18:19:59 | 132438 | Jhon | 20210002 |
| 7/18/2021 18:19:59 | 132465 | Jhon | 20210002 |
| 7/18/2021 18:19:59 | 133016 | Jhon | 20210002 |

`the current script was done below`

```
function formatData() {
 // File
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 // Get responseData sheet
 var rawData = ss.getSheetByName('documentTransmittal');

 // Input data
 var data = rawData.getRange("A2:D").getValues(); // Gets titles and options in a single call to the sheet

 // Initialise an array that will hold the output
 var outputArray = [];

 // Name a variable to hold the data from each set of options
 var options;

 // Start looping through the data
 for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {

 // Split the document with individual no.
 options = data[row][1].split(", ");

 // Loop through the array of split options and place each of them in a new row
 for (var element = 0; element < options.length; element++) {

 outputArray.push([data[row][0], // Place the title in a new row
                  options[element]]); // Place one option in the 2nd column of the row

  } // Options loop ends here

 } // Data loop ends here

 // Get processedData sheet
 var processedData = ss.getSheetByName('responseData');

 // Get last row in processedData sheet
 var lastRow = processedData.getLastRow();

 // Post the outputArray to the sheet in a single call
 processedData.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, outputArray.length,
 outputArray[2].length).setValues(outputArray);

}
```

`above only can help get 2 row data only`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK but there are a few areas where it could be improved.

**Last Row**

As it is written, the code converts the entire "documentTransmittal" sheet. In this case, the last row will always be zero and there is nothing be gained by  using `var lastRow = processedData.getLastRow();`

**Data Range**

Specifying an entire column ("D") means that the range could be 1000 rows (or more) deep even though the actual data might be a couple of rows. This is not a particular problem, but the `getDataRange` method is an alternative to select only the range containing data.

- Delete: `var data = rawData.getRange("A2:D").getValues();`
- Substiute: `var data = rawData.getDataRange().getValues();`

**Creating each row**

Your code only inserts the Transmission time and the elements of the Document Number. The needs to be expanded to include the "Recipient Name" and the "Document transmittal ref".

- Delete: `outputArray.push([data[row][0], // Place the title in a new row options[element]]); // Place one option in the 2nd column of the row`
- Substitute: `outputArray.push([data[row][0], // Place the title in a new row options[element],// Place one option in the 2nd column of the row data[row][2], // Place the Recipient name data[row][3]]); // Place Ref No.`

---

**Sample data**

[image: Sample]

---

**Script Output**

[image: Script]

Comment: i found a new issue here, the old data will be repeated (copy and paste) when i run the script
the doc transmittal is a response data that collected from google form
the data will always updated when received the respond from responder

how do i solve it with script ?

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that but you didn't mention it it in your question. You need to modify your script to reflect a couple of things. First, trigger the script with an installable `[onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)` trigger. Enable [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to get the new response. Last, append only the new response.

Comment: I suggest that you do some research on `onFormSubmit` triggers - there are lot of precedents on Webapps and StackOverflow. If you get stuck, raise it as a new question.

Comment: Just still stuck at there, I tried to set the triggers to run the script, but the no one is show the result as wanted

Comment: any advise to me or sample , to telling me where i should start with ?